# Problem resizing an itemize environment with a \scalebox: "Something's wrong"

Tags: errors, boxes, itemize, scaling

I have a `\block` containing a `\itemize`:

```
\begin{block}{title}
  % \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{itemize}
      \item 1...
      \item 2...
  \end{itemize}
  % }  
\end{block}
```

I try to use `\scalebox`and `resizebox` to scale it, but I got an error `ERROR: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` Could anyone help?

Comment: use a smaller font size ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that the `scalebox` command needs to operate on a `box`, and the `itemize` environment is not in one.

Perhaps the easiest way to fix this is to put it in a `vbox`

```
\scalebox{0.8}{%
\vbox{%
    \begin{itemize}
      \item 1...
      \item 2...
     \end{itemize}
 }}
```

Or you might prefer a `minipage`

```
\scalebox{0.8}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
      \item 1...
      \item 2...
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
}
```

Comment: unsung hero anyone? :P

Comment: @percusse you're right- every cloud has a silver lining :) I don't think anyone would get that badge on tex exchange though- the voting is too good :)

Comment: Don't worry with an upvote, I'm here! `:)`

Comment: Ah.... those totally unintuitive, arbitrary details that make Tex such a painless language to work with...