# Enumerate environment inside scalebox

Tags: enumerate, fontsize, text-manipulation, scalebox

I want to reduce the text below to a scale 0.5:

```
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1-2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
```

However, When I use

```
\scalebox{0.5}{
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1-2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}}
```

an error occurs.

When I use `\parbox` together `\scalebox` the paragraph changes to the right:

```
\scalebox{0.5}{
\parbox{0.88\textwidth}{
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1-2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}}}
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: don't scale, (`\scalebox` is like `\mbox` and can not take display lists) just use a smaller font, eg `\tiny`

Comment: you can use a nested scalebox (but beware omitting `%` afte `{` ) if you want help though please provide a complete example that shows the problem. what do you mean by "changes to the right" ?

Comment: Did you try as suggested at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/problem-resizing-an-itemize-environment-with-a-scalebox-somethings-wrong